# A strengthening of a known inequality; looking for a neater solution

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a\ge b\ge c > 0$ then

> $$
> \begin{split}
> \frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+b)} + \frac{(b-c)^2}{(b+c)} & \ge \sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}- (a+b+c) \\&\ge \frac{(a-b)^2}{\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}a+\frac{5-\sqrt{3}}{2} b} +\frac{(b-c)^2}{(1+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}})b+(2-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}) c}
> \end{split}
> $$

This is a strengthening of an inequality found [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h3233403).

---

Notes:

1. Found the RHS inequality by choosing the coefficients in such a way that (after a substitution $a=u+v+w$, $b=u+v$, $c=u$), the coefficients of all of the monomials in $u$, $v$, $w$ in the numerator of the difference of the squares of sides are $\ge 0$ ( also known as the Buffalo way, but it goes back  at least to Adolf Hurwitz).  The possible coefficients in the denominator form a convex set of a fairly simple kind ( a product in fact). The choices are those of a vertex. One can do that for every $n$, the formulas are not that complicated.
2. Found the LHS inequality by numerical optimization. In fact, one cannot do it with the previous method.
3. A general comment: one could compose  many inequalities about the extreme of some algebraic function on some semialgebraic set. In a fixed dimension the answer can be given in principle as a real algebraic number ( if not infinite). For inequalities that involve $n$ unknowns, where $n$ is arbitrary, things can be complicated. Some , ( the mean inequalities, or the Newton/Maclaurin inequalties $\&$c) are established for all $n$. It may not be feasible to do that in general.

---

At this stage I don't see a neater way to prove it. Any feedback would be appreciated!

In a previous version the LHS was not correct, I thank @River Li: for pointing out that.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer.**

- For the left inequality

It suffices to prove that
$$\left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+b)} + \frac{(b-c)^2}{(b+c)} + (a + b + c)\right)^2\ge 3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)$$
or
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+b)} + \frac{(b-c)^2}{(b+c)}\right)^2 + 2\left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+b)} + \frac{(b-c)^2}{(b+c)}\right)(a + b + c)\\[6pt]
 &\qquad  + (a + b + c)^2 \ge 3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)
\end{align*}
or (using $(u+v)^2 \ge 4uv$)
$$\begin{align*}
 &4\cdot \frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+b)} \cdot \frac{(b-c)^2}{(b+c)} + 2\left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+b)} + \frac{(b-c)^2}{(b+c)}\right)(a + b + c)\\[6pt]
 &\qquad  + (a + b + c)^2 \ge 3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)
\end{align*}$$
or (multiplying both sides by $(a+b)(b+c)$)
$$ \left( 5\,{a}^{2}-5\,ab+2\,{b}^{2} \right) {c}^{2}+ \left( -5\,{a}^{2
}b+4\,a{b}^{2}-3\,{b}^{3} \right) c+2\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}-3\,a{b}^{3}+3\,{
 b}^{4}
\ge 0$$
which is true since $5\,{a}^{2}-5\,ab+2\,{b}^{2} \ge 0$ and
\begin{align*}
 &4\cdot \left( 5\,{a}^{2}-5\,ab+2\,{b}^{2} \right) \cdot (2\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}-3\,a{b}^{3}+3\,{
  b}^{4})\\
 &\qquad - (-5\,{a}^{2
 }b+4\,a{b}^{2}-3\,{b}^{3})^2\\
={}& 15(a-b)^4b^2 \ge 0.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: @orangeskid Yes, it is not difficult to prove it if any solutions are allowed.

Comment: @orangeskid Don't worry about the bounty. Just ignore this partial answer.

Comment: @orangeskid I am interested in a solution which is easily verified (even by hand). I don't have one for the right inequality. We are "looking for a neater solution".